# How can i list all display suite layout templates used

Tags: display-suite

Is there a way to list all display suite templates that are currently being used in the various view modes?

To clarify: I have many content types, and many view modes, AND many custom made ds layouts. It's becomes a big mix and i would like to get an overview which ds layouts are being used by which view mode / content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he's asking to get an overview of of which bundle / view mode uses which template file.

That's currently not easy to fine in the backend - however this is something we want to add add some place.

The fastest way to get an overview is to go to the database and look into the 'ds_layout_settings' table. The 'layout' column holds the machine name of the template used.

Comment: Yup, thats what i was looking for, Thanks! ya, would be great to have this available in the admin. You get going creating so many view modes and templates then you want to clean up and dont know if maybe one you want to delete is being used and where :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, go to to the content or select the content type from Structure/Content Type, select the content type e.g. Projects, then select Manage Display, then scroll to the bottom, and you will see a drop down, select that and you will see all the layouts possible